# How to emulate a multi-parameter side-effect Function

Tags: java, guava

I would like to emulate the following interface:

```
interface MultiSideEffectFunction<T> {
    void action(T first, T second);
}
```

(it would save me from having to introduce a new interface)

is there a preferred Guava approach to doing this?

Note: I thought about doing it with

```
Function<Pair<T>, Void>
```

but there are two problems which makes the creation of a new interface preferable:

1. One must define a class called `Pair<T>`, which looks a lot like a `Map.Entry<T, T>` with more appropriate getter names (as a second question: is there a Guava type like this?).
2. The `Void` return type is always a pain - it would be better to have a genuine `void` signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

The preferred Guava approach is to write your own interface.

In particular, do *not* use `Function`; `Function` should only be used when the function doesn't have side effects.

Guava deliberately lacks a `Pair` type; we advise that any time you need a pair, you create your own class that attaches *useful* names to the two values, rather than the utterly uninformative "first" and "second".  (The prototypical example is for GPS coordinates; a class entitled `LatLong` is much more informative than a `Pair<Double, Double>`.)

Answer (score 3):

The Guava team makes no bones about the fact that they they only provide basic functional idioms and that they are not interested in recreating a full functional-programming API.  FOr that, you could look at several other APIs.  And some of those APIs support side-effect inducing "functional" objects, even though side-effects are antithetical to pure functional programming models (which I say is fine, since Java is *never* going to be a truly functional language, even after lambdas).

But anyway, as an example API, [**Jedi**](http://jedi.codehaus.org/) provides the [`Command`](http://jedi.codehaus.org/javadoc/jedi/functional/Command2.html) class for exactly what you are looking for.  In [**Functional Java**](http://functionaljava.org/), they provide the [`Effect`](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/Effect.html) class, which I think is about the same thing.

Btw, in your example, you would probably want to provide multiple Type Vars instead of just `<T>`, so that each of your input types could vary from one another.

(**JUST EDITED** for glaring typos)

Comment: thanks Kevin - Jedi is news to me. However, I find it to be a curiosity rather than something I'll likely use. If they are going to make a library to declutter Java, which includes annotations that generate code at the compilation stage, then I think they could have best spent their time coming up with an annotation-based solution to patterns such as getter/setter/listener (the number one cause of boilerplate in Java, IMHO). They are also intentionally bloating the "Conventional Java" examples by refusing to use the advanced for loop - that's just bad marketing and doesn't fool anyone.

Comment: OMG, I just discovered [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) and about to see if I can get it working between Netbeans/Maven. Kevin, I thank you more than you can possibly imagine for sparking me to pursue this line of inquiry!

Comment: Good point on Jedi's examples... I hadn't noticed that.  I'm not a fan of compile time annotation-processing, which is why I developed a library to wrap methods as function-like objects at runtime, working on top of libraries like Guava, Functional Java, and Jedi.