# Does Guava Lists.transform guarantee order?

Tags: java, guava

Can I rely on order while transforming ?

```
public class DtoFunc implements Function<Entity,DTO>{

    Entity previousEntity;

    @Override
    public DTO apply(Entity entity){
       DTO dto = new DTO();
       // do transforming

       previousEntity = entity;
       return dto;
    }
}
```

as you can see that I store state in my function, and I rely that when I invoke Lists.transform(entityList,new DtoFunc()) it will transform consequentially
.Does it tranform in sequential order ?? Can I rely on it ?

**CORRECT ANSWER** : Transformation order depends on access from transformed list because transformation is lazy. Function have to be stateless because Guava is not thread safe.

Comment: Functions should preferably be stateless. Storing the previous entity to process the next one is a code smell, and might indicate that a for loop would be better. See the caveats in https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Comment: @Etienne Neveu : I've read the link, but I did not find smth about stateless?

Comment: Indeed, the wiki doesn't talk about "state". I was referring to the general philosophy behind Guava's functional idioms: "Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code.". In your case, using a stateful function is confusing, and could cause weird bugs because Lists#transform() applies them lazily (as explained in the answers), so a for-loop might be preferable. Here is a link to a Guava team member saying that functions shouldn't have side effects (e.g. stateless): http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249179/142983

Comment: I use list as Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(myList,myFunc)); - no lazy !!

Comment: `Function` is expected to be used in a stateless way.  You should _not_ be using it if you require state.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman : I dont understand. Could you please explain why not ?  And I will be greatful if you give me answer : can I use the Function as Spring bean, I want to use repository to get some additional elements from db that are participating in transformation, and that's why I want to autowire dao to function bean.

Comment: More or less _everywhere_ that `Function` is used in Guava will behave in undefined ways if the function has state.

Comment: I think you should write Guava is not thread safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)):

> The function is applied lazily, invoked when needed.

I.e. if you do this:

```
List<Foo> fooList = newArrayList<Foo>();
// ...
List<Bar> barList = Lists.transform(fooArrayList, fooToBarFunction);
barList.get(5);
```

then Guava will get the element with index 5 from `fooList`, apply `fooToBarFunction` to it, and return that to the caller. The elements with other indices won't be touched.

If `fooList` is not a RandomAccessList, then the result may be different:

```
List<Foo> fooList = newLinkedList<Foo>();
// ...
List<Bar> barList = Lists.transform(fooArrayList, fooToBarFunction);
barList.get(5);
```

This call would access the element with index 5 by iterating from element 0 to element 5, possibly applying the transformation function for each element in between.

Therefore, the order of transforming is not guaranteed. However, if you can control the order of access of the returned list, *and if the source list is of type* `RandomAccess` then the order of invocation of `fooToBarFunction` is exactly the same order as the order of invocations on the result list. This follows from the documentation that the function is applied lazily when you access the returned list and the guarantee that the returned list implements RandomAccess, if the source list does.

Comment: Sorrry, but "order of transforming is not guaranteed." and "xactly the same order as the order of invocations on the result list" are not conflicting ??
I didn't get the correct answer, can I rely on order or not ?

Comment: @Playmate: The keyword here is *guaranteed* - Guava does not make any guarantees about the order, but due to the lazy nature of the transformation function it happens to be the same order.

Comment: Omg, Guava does not guarantees but t happens to be the same order ? Are you kidding me ? Sorry, but I dont understand how Guava does not guarantee but transformation function it happens to be the same order, I see these phrases are contradictory.

Comment: @Playmate: you can rely on the order if only you control the access to the resulting list. So if you use an iterator and iterate over it one at a time, then the order in which the function is called is exactly the order of the elements. However, if you use remove(Object), then this may iterate through until a matching entry has been found, a subsequent remove(Object) call may start afresh or do something different.

Comment: Thx a lot, finally I got it :)

Comment: Can you give a example, because I have test your info and I got that lists tranform guarantees the order.

Comment: @Playmate: Try this: Make an ArrayList<Integer> with 5 elements (0-4), transform it to a List<Long>, with the transformation function having state and simply doing (long)intValue. Then do a get(3), a get(2), and a remove(Integer.valueOf(-1)) - the order of invocation will be 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Integer.valuOf(-1) ??? Did you check it before have posted?

Comment: I've test your example, yes I got your order.Summarazing : transformation order depends on access from transformed list because transformation is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadocs:

> The returned list is a transformed view of `fromList`; changes to `fromList` will be reflected in the returned list and vice versa.

It's not explicitly stated, but I think this and the rest of the description imply that the order will be preserved.

Edit: The keyword here is *view*: The returned list is backed by the original, and the docs also explain that the function is applied lazily when needed. So yes, the order will be the same. Depending on what you want to do with the list, Guava even recommends that in certain cases it might be wiser to create a real copy rather than a transformed view.

Comment: It is explicitly stated. If the returned List is a transformed view the element order must remain the same. Because the order is not transformed. Only the elements.

Comment: @René Link Thank you, I just realized this myself after thinking the mechanism and words through.

Comment: The other key word is `List`, which is specifically defined as ordered.

Comment: Is the correct answer is - yes I can rely on oreder ?